# In spark iterate through each column and find the max length

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregation, maxlength

I am new to spark scala and I have following situation as below
I have a table "TEST_TABLE" on cluster(can be hive table)
I am converting that to dataframe
as:

```
scala> val testDF = spark.sql("select * from TEST_TABLE limit 10")
```

Now the DF can be viewed as

```
scala> testDF.show()

COL1|COL2|COL3  
----------------
abc|abcd|abcdef 
a|BCBDFG|qddfde 
MN|1234B678|sd
```

I want an output like below

```
COLUMN_NAME|MAX_LENGTH
       COL1|3
       COL2|8
       COL3|6
```

Is this feasible to do so in spark scala?

Answer (score 8):

Plain and simple:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = spark.table("TEST_TABLE")
df.select(df.columns.map(c => max(length(col(c)))): _*)
```

Comment: can you please convert this to PySpark as well? Thanks

Comment: @BadBoy777 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656561/pyspark-max-string-length-for-each-column-in-the-dataframe/64675496#64675496

I've added pyspark code for a different question.

Answer (score 4):

You can try in the following way:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{length, max}
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(("abc","abcd","abcdef"),
          ("a","BCBDFG","qddfde"),
          ("MN","1234B678","sd"),
          (null,"","sd")).toDF("COL1","COL2","COL3")
df.cache()
val output = df.columns.map(c => (c, df.agg(max(length(df(s"$c")))).as[Int].first())).toSeq.toDF("COLUMN_NAME", "MAX_LENGTH")
        +-----------+----------+
        |COLUMN_NAME|MAX_LENGTH|
        +-----------+----------+
        |       COL1|         3|
        |       COL2|         8|
        |       COL3|         6|
        +-----------+----------+
```

I think it's good idea to cache input dataframe `df` to make the computation faster.

Comment: Great Solution, However, My actual data has null and blanks so ".as[Int]" is throwing error, If I remove the ".as[Int]" then its asking for "Encoder"

Error:
    
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for 
    org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    - field (class: "org.apache.spark.sql.Row", name: "_2")
    - root class: "scala.Tuple2"

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to regenerate the issue you are facing. I've edited my answer and I've inserted row with null and blank but It is not showing any error. Can you please give sample rows so that i can regenerate the issue ? .

Comment: Hi, I have simply change the .as[Int] to .as[String] that worked for now

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it helps you ? :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one more way to get the report of column names in vertical

```
scala> val df = Seq(("abc","abcd","abcdef"),("a","BCBDFG","qddfde"),("MN","1234B678","sd")).toDF("COL1","COL2","COL3")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [COL1: string, COL2: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show(false)
+----+--------+------+
|COL1|COL2    |COL3  |
+----+--------+------+
|abc |abcd    |abcdef|
|a   |BCBDFG  |qddfde|
|MN  |1234B678|sd    |
+----+--------+------+

scala> val columns = df.columns
columns: Array[String] = Array(COL1, COL2, COL3)

scala> val df2 = columns.foldLeft(df) { (acc,x) => acc.withColumn(x,length(col(x))) }
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [COL1: int, COL2: int ... 1 more field]

scala> df2.select( columns.map(x => max(col(x))):_* ).show(false)
+---------+---------+---------+
|max(COL1)|max(COL2)|max(COL3)|
+---------+---------+---------+
|3        |8        |6        |
+---------+---------+---------+


scala> df3.flatMap( r => { (0 until r.length).map( i => (columns(i),r.getInt(i)) ) } ).show(false)
+----+---+
|_1  |_2 |
+----+---+
|COL1|3  |
|COL2|8  |
|COL3|6  |
+----+---+


scala>
```

To get the results into Scala collections, say Map()

```
scala> val result = df3.flatMap( r => { (0 until r.length).map( i => (columns(i),r.getInt(i)) ) } ).as[(String,Int)].collect.toMap
result: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(COL1 -> 3, COL2 -> 8, COL3 -> 6)

scala> result
res47: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(COL1 -> 3, COL2 -> 8, COL3 -> 6)

scala>
```