# Get max length in column for each column in a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe like that

```
+-----------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
|     column1     |    column2    | column3  |  column4  |
+-----------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
| a               | bbbbb         | cc       | >dddddddd |
| >aaaaaaaaaaaaaa | bb            | c        | dddd      |
| aa              | >bbbbbbbbbbbb | >ccccccc | ddddd     |
| aaaaa           | bbbb          | ccc      | d         |
+-----------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
```

I would like to find a length of the longest element in each column to obtain something like that

```
+---------+-----------+
| column  | maxLength |
+---------+-----------+
| column1 |        14 |
| column2 |        12 |
| column3 |         7 |
| column4 |         8 |
+---------+-----------+
```

I know how to do it column by column but don't know how to tell Spark - `Do it for all columns` .

I am using Scala Spark.

Comment: Please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263293/in-spark-iterate-through-each-column-and-find-the-max-length

Answer (score 1):

You can use `agg` function `max` and `length` function to achieve it as

```
val x = df.columns.map(colName => {
  (colName, df.agg(max(length(col(colName)))).head().getAs[Integer](0))
}).toSeq.toDF("column", "maxLength")
```

Output:

```
+-------+---------+
|column |maxLength|
+-------+---------+
|column1|14       |
|column2|13       |
|column3|8        |
|column4|9        |
+-------+---------+
```

Other way is

```
df.select(df.columns.map(c => max(length(col(c))).as(s"max_${c}")): _*)
```

Output:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|max_column1|max_column2|max_column3|max_column4|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|14         |13         |8          |9          |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Nice and simple. How can we do it in python?

Comment: @koiralo it doesn't work with complex struct