# pyspark max string length for each column in the dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am trying this in databricks .
Please let me know the pyspark libraries needed to be imported and code to get the below output in Azure databricks
pyspark

example:-
input dataframe :-

```
|     column1     |    column2    | column3  |  column4  |

| a               | bbbbb         | cc       | >dddddddd |
| >aaaaaaaaaaaaaa | bb            | c        | dddd      |
| aa              | >bbbbbbbbbbbb | >ccccccc | ddddd     |
| aaaaa           | bbbb          | ccc      | d         |
```

output dataframe :-

```
| column  | maxLength |

| column1 |        14 |
| column2 |        12 |
| column3 |         7 |
| column4 |         8 |
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
>>> df = sc.parallelize([['a','bbbbb','ccc','ddd'],['aaaa','bbb','ccccccc', 'dddd']]).toDF(["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"])
>>> df1 = df.select([sf.length(col).alias(col) for col in df.columns])
>>> df1.groupby().max().show()
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|max(column1)|max(column2)|max(column3)|max(column4)|
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|           4|           5|           7|           4|
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

then use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe) to melt previous dataframe

**Edit:** (From [Iterate through each column and find the max length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74915029/iterate-through-each-column-and-find-the-max-length))

Single line select

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, length, max

df=df.select([max(length(col(name))).alias(name) for name in df.schema.names])
```

Output
[image: Output]

As Rows

```
df = df.select([max(length(col(name))).alias(name) for name in df.schema.names])
row=df.first().asDict()
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(col=name, length=row[name]) for name in df.schema.names], ['col', 'length'])
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks this worked and also taking less time to execute :) :)

Comment: @VIGNESHR Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as an answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @E.ZY. EXCELENT solution. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.