# Iterate through each column and find the max length

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to get the maximum length from each column from a pyspark dataframe.

Following is the sample dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType

data2 = [("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000),
    ("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",-1)
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
```

I tried to implement the [solution provided in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263293/in-spark-iterate-through-each-column-and-find-the-max-length) but could not convert it.

Comment: Does this answer work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64675496

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, length, max


df=df.select([max(length(col(name))) for name in df.schema.names])
```

Result

[image: Output]

**Edit:** For reference: Converting to Rows (As asked here, updated there as well - [pyspark max string length for each column in the dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656561/pyspark-max-string-length-for-each-column-in-the-dataframe/64675496#64675496))

```
df = df.select([max(length(col(name))).alias(name) for name in df.schema.names])
row=df.first().asDict()
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(col=name, length=row[name]) for name in df.schema.names], ['col', 'length'])
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: How do are you using `row`? I am getting the error: `NameError: name 'row' is not defined`.

Comment: @nam Updated the answer, thanks for pointing out - there was a missing line.